# I am getting default header in the react-native android ,How to fix that header?

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, react-navigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPDxO.jpg)How I can change that header in the react-native, After giving build I am getting that default android header.Please me out with this issue

Comment: please provide more details, code snippets if possible

Comment: also define what kind of changes you want to apply

Comment: I want to remove the top header that's it

Comment: what `Stack.Screen` does the screenshot correspond to? you can edit your question to add more details, it's not necessary to create an answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
  <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              headerTransparent: false,
              headerTitleAlign: "center",
              headerTitleStyle: {
                fontSize: 13,
                fontWeight: "normal",
                letterSpacing: 1,
                color: "#fff",
              },
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "#7862FF",
              },
              headerTintColor: "#fff",
              headerBackTitleVisible: false,
            }}
          >
            {loginState.userToken == null ? (
              <>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Login"
                  component={SignInScreen}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="SignUp"
                  component={SignUpScreen}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Forgotpassword"
                  component={Forgetpassword}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Landing"
                  component={LandingScreen}
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="Dashboard"
                  component={DashboardScreen}
                  options={{ title: "Dashboard", headerTransparent: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="ArCamera"
                  component={CreateArTag}
                  options={{ title: "", headerTransparent: true }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="ViewArTag"
                  component={ViewArTag}
                  options={{ title: "", headerTransparent: true }}
                />
              </>
            )}
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```